# Why openssl encryption cipher aes-256-cbc not require IV though i define cipher mode CBC

Tags: openssl, cryptography, cbc-mode

When i try to execute below command

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in ./imp.txt -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -out ./imp.enc
```

it will ask me for password. which i provide and it created imp.enc.
After that, i execute below command to decrypt whatever i encrypt in above command.

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in ./imp.enc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 10000 -out ./imp.dec
```

which also works fine.
So here, my question is, **Though i define the cipher mode as CBC, why these operation not ask me for IV ? Does CBC cipher mode can work without IV ?**

Comment: CBC by definition requires an IV. However, here it is not passed directly, but derived together with the key from the password (and a randomly generated salt during encryption) using a key derivation function (namely PBKDF2). If you want to specify the key and IV directly, you must use the *-K* and *-iv* options. S. [*openssl enc*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html).